# Base URL that works for html in files and on website?

Tags: html, href, radix

Like many developers I put my images in /images, css in /css, and js in /js.  This way, no matter what the URL/directory structure, the site can simply reference /css/style.css or /js/jquery.

Problem is when I try opening the html from a directory, the paths are screwed up.  It assumes / is C:/

I'd like to be able to preview html files in a directory before putting them into a CMS on the web, but don't know how.  Can  somehow be used to handle this with minimal hassle?

Comment: Just run a local webserver. The more differences there are between the test system and the live system, the more chance of something going wrong when you transfer them.

Comment: That's way too much work.  I -have- a local webserver, etc.  I just want to be able to make a quick check of the graphics and CSS from a designer before working on it.  Also, the designer needs to check their own work and make sure they set up paths, etc. correctly.

Answer (score 1):

By putting a slash in front of your path, you're making it an absolute path. You should use absolute paths as rarely as possible - instead, use relative paths.

Say you have a directory structure like this:

```
/website
    /html
        /css
             style.css
        test.html
        script.js
    /newcss
        newstyle.css
```

If you're in `test.html` and you need to refer to `style.css`, the relative path would be `css/style.css`. If you need to refer to `script.js`, the relative path would be just `script.js`. If you need to refer to newstyle.css, the relative path would be `../newcss/newstyle.css` (the .. means "go up one directory level").

This has the benefit of making your code portable - you could copy the `website` folder anywhere you wanted, on any system, even to your websever, and it would work. Both *nix and Windows systems obey these rules.

Comment: There is no should/shouldn't rule set here. It's entirely dependent on your working/dev/prod environments and preferences.

Comment: I prefer to use absolute paths over relative. Simply because that way your script can easily be transported, but it also depends on the situation and the structure and preference.

Comment: Alex, if I followed your advice, I'd need to make separate copies of the css, images, and javascript.  I've got URLs of varying length: e.g. http://domain.com/, http://domain.com/articles, http://domain.com/articles/article-name.

Answer (score 1):

Using root-relative links is great but, as you see, can cause issues when working locally.

Ideally, you'd set up a local web server on your machine and preview that way rather than just using the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider setting up a local server like [XAMPP](http://xampp.org). That way, your files will be previewable on `http://127.0.0.1` and your absolute paths can be made to work just like on the web. XAMPP comes with a default `htdocs` directory into which you would put your file structure.

It may take some time of setting it up and getting into it, though.